# How do I add a video to my anki flash card?

Tags: anki

I have some videos in my phone (not on youtube) that I want to add to my Anki flash cards.
How can I do that?
I am using anki 2.0 on my computer (ubuntu) and don't want to upgrade to 2.1 as I want to continue using cloze overlapper which is not yet available with 2.1

I tried uploading to google drive and using that link like this replacing youtube link:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AKluWwojOls" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```